# Back to back useState not updating first state, only the second one

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I am trying to have a general function which run setState twice, however, the first setState will not update. Are there any way to get around it? or how to fix this issue?

Parent

```js
const [data, setData] = useState({});
const updateData = (key, value) => {
  console.log(key, value);
  setData({ ...data, [key]: value });
};
...
 <div>
    Num 1: {data.num1}, Num2: {data.num2}
 </div>
 <Child updateData={updateData} />
```

Child

```js
const { updateData } = props;
const onClick = () => {
  updateData("num1", 1);
  updateData("num2", 2);
};
return <button onClick={onClick}> Click here </button>
```

`console.log` return both values being called, but only 1 value being updated

[codesandbox example here](https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-leavitt-l47tc?file=/src/Parent.js)

(After some testing, even calliing both in the same parent function, if calling `setData` twice, it still wont work (see Simplify.js)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While you could use a callback so that the argument contains the currently updated state, including prior state setters that've run but before a re-rendering has occurred:

```
const updateData = (key, value) => {
  setData(data => ({ ...data, [key]: value }));
};
```

If you have a limited number of possible properties in the `data` variable, consider using separate states instead:

```
const [num1, setNum1] = useState(0);
const [num2, setNum2] = useState(0);
```

```
const onClick = () => {
  setNum1(num1 + 1);
  setNum2(num2 + 2);
};
```

Comment: Thx, got it solved with first solution. I will mark you as the answer in a few minutes once stackoverflow allow me to do so.. Also I had over 20 properties that need to update this way, so second solution doesnt work for me in this case.

Answer (score 2):

`setState` is asynchronous so if you do the two calls one after the other in the same function the state won't have updated for the second call and you won't get what you want.

The best practise in general for when setting state based off previous state is to use a callback.

```
const updateData = (key, value) => {
  setData(prevData => { ...prevData, [key]: value });
};

const onClick = () => {
  updateData("num1", 1);
  updateData("num2", 2);
};
```

Comment: SO will not let me edit, but want to say: parenthesis are required around `{ ...prevData, [key]: value }` so it's like: `setData(prevData => ({ ...prevData, [key]: value }));`